# Swift animate with duration xib

Tags: swift, xcode

I am wanting to create a subview which slides in when my viewController loads.

However the view is presenting without the animation effect, how would I get the view to animate?

I am calling on my viewContoller:

> menuBarView.show(viewController: self)

```
   class menuBarView {

    static func show(viewController: UIViewController){

        menuBarSubView = UINib(nibName: "MenuBar", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
        menuBarSubView?.frame.size.height = viewController.view.frame.height * 0.1
        menuBarSubView?.frame.size.width = viewController.view.frame.width
        menuBarSubView?.frame.origin.x = viewController.view.frame.origin.x
        menuBarSubView?.frame.origin.y = viewController.view.frame.origin.y - menuBarSubView.frame.height
        menuBarSubView?.tag = 1
        viewController.view.addSubview(menuBarSubView!)

        viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            viewController.view.viewWithTag(1)?.frame.origin.y += (viewController.view.viewWithTag(1)?.frame.height)!
            viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }
     }
```

Comment: I don't mean to be that guy, but the capitalised first letter in the variable name is freaking me out.

Comment: haha fair point